# Lost records at line "data_in.read().replace("<*", "<").replace("*\n", "")"

Tags: python, regex, csv, python-3.x

I have been trying to figure out why 47 records out of 700+ records are missing from the database after running the code below. Please help to see whether this is a coding error or memory limitation in Python.

```
def create_csv_file():
    source_html = open(r'C:\\Users\\Admin\\SkyDrive\\eCommerce\\Servi-fied\\Raw Data\\EMA - Electricians (Raw).txt', 'r')
    bs_object = BeautifulSoup(source_html, "html.parser")

    data_out = open(r'C:\\Users\\Admin\\SkyDrive\\eCommerce\\Servi-fied\\Raw Data\\temp.csv', 'w+')
    data_in = open(r'C:\\Users\\Admin\\SkyDrive\\eCommerce\\Servi-fied\\Raw Data\\temp.csv', 'r')
    csv_file1 = open(r'C:\\Users\\Admin\\SkyDrive\\eCommerce\\Servi-fied\\Raw Data\\EMA - Electricians (Processed).csv', 'w+')
    csv_file2 = open(r'C:\\Users\\Admin\\SkyDrive\\eCommerce\\Servi-fied\\Raw Data\\EMA - Electricians (Processed).csv', 'r')
    csv_file3 = open(r'C:\\Users\\Admin\\SkyDrive\\eCommerce\\Servi-fied\\Raw Data\\EMA - Electricians (Processed).csv', 'w+')

    writer1 = csv.writer(data_out, delimiter='<', skipinitialspace=True)

    table = bs_object.find("table", {"id":"gasOfferSearch"})
    rows = table.findAll("tr")

    try:
        # Iterates through the list, but skips the first record (i.e. the table header)
        for row in rows[1:]:
            csvRow = []
            for cell in row.findAll(['td','th']):
                # Replace "\n" with a whitespace; replace <br> tags with 5 whitespaces
                line = str(cell).replace('\n', ' ').replace('<br>', '     ')
                # Replace 2 or more spaces with "\n"
                line = re.sub('\s{2,}', '*', line)
                # Converts results to a BeautifulSoup object
                line_bsObj = BeautifulSoup(line, "html.parser")
                # Strips: Removes all tags and trailing and leading whitespaces
                # Replace: Removes all quotation marks
                csvRow.append(line_bsObj.get_text().strip().replace('"',''))

            # Converts the string into a csv file
            writer1.writerow(csvRow)

        # Reads from the temp file and replaces all "<*" with "<"
        # TODO: Issue - 47 records missing with replacement
        temp_string = data_in.read().replace("<*", "<").replace("*\n", "")
        csv_file1.write(temp_string)

        # Clear the temp_string variable
        temp_string = ""
        for line in csv_file2.readlines():
            temp_string += line.replace("*", "<", 1)

        csv_file3.write(temp_string)

    finally:
        source_html.close()
        csv_file1.close()
        csv_file2.close()
        data_out.close()
        data_in.close()

        # Remove the temp file
        # os.remove('C:\\Users\\Admin\\SkyDrive\\eCommerce\\Servi-fied\\Raw Data\\temp.csv')

    return None
```

Comment: It ends on the line "return None". After that this function is called in a separate line. You mean I got the indentation wrong in the code?

Comment: I found the `return None` after I made the comment, and adjusted your code accordingly.  Sounds like I guessed right.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what is going wrong, but here's some general advice:

- don't open the same file three different times at the same time (`csv_file[1,2,3]` are the same)
- add `print` commands to double check what's going on:

  - put one just before the `for now in rows` that prints out the total number of rows
  - put them around the `temp_string = data_in...` to make sure those numbers are correct
- if all that fails to show the problem, post a couple sample records for us to look at